# Why is the NodeJS MySQL adding an extra backspace during query on correctly escaped JSON array?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, regex, express

As the title says I am trying to escape a JSON array in NodeJS with the MySQL library. I am use the mysql.escape() function, and printing it to the console correctly formats it as `['1\'/\"','2','3']`, but when I query it, for some reason the query adds an extra backslash for no apparent reason, causing it to throw an incorrect syntax error i.e `['1\\'/\\"','2','3']`. The query I am using is:

```
INSERT INTO Recipes VALUES (uuid(), uuid_short(), '${USER_ID}', '${FAMILY_ID}', CURDATE(), ${connection.escape(recipe.TTM)}, ${connection.escape(recipe.name)}, ${connection.escape(recipe.description)}, '{"ingredients": ${handleEscape(recipe.ingredients)}}', '{"prep": ${handleEscape(recipe.prep)}}', '{"cooking": ${handleEscape(recipe.steps)}}', '{"tags": ${handleEscape(recipe.tags)}}', '${SHARING}', '${newPath}', 0)
```

The query that MySQL is recieving is:

```
INSERT INTO Recipes VALUES (uuid(), uuid_short(), 'a1e08ba2-cddd-11ea-9273-e4b97a23a86a', '6e27ec4e-cdf3-11ea-9029-e4b97a23a86a', CURDATE(), '1', '1', '1', '{"ingredients": ['1\\'/\\"','2','3']}', '{"prep": ['1']}', '{"cooking": ['1']}', '{"tags": ['1']}', 'public', 'uploads/1601334839980-slide#4.jpeg.JPG', 0)
```

For reference, handleEscape is a function which returns (the correct) escape string. I'm at my wits end with trying to fix the error. Does anyone know the solution?